# a full element in a $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a unital $C^*$-algebra,$a$ is a full element in $A$.Show that there exist $n\in \Bbb N$ and $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n,y_1,y_2,\cdots y_n \in A$ such that $1_A = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i a y_i$.

Let $I:=\bigg \lbrace \sum_{i=1}^n x_i a y_i : x_i, y_i \in A, \ n\in \mathbb{N} \bigg \rbrace$,$J$ is the closure of $I$,since $a$ is full,then $a$ is not contained in any proper closed two sided ideal in $A$.We can conclude that $J=A$,then $1_A\in J$.How to prove that $1_A$  has the form of $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i a y_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the collection of invertible elements of $A$ is open, there is some invertible element $b\in I$, and we may write 
$$b=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iay_i.$$
Then we have 
$$1_A=b^{-1}b=\sum_{i=1}^n(b^{-1}x_i)ay_i.$$

Comment: I don't understand why there exist some invertible element $b\in I$.Since $I$ is dense in $A$,for $1_A \in A$,there exists $i\in I$ such that $\|1_A-i\|\leq 1$,then $i$ is invertible,but $i^{-1}$ may not lie in $I$.

Comment: If you agree that $1_A=\sum_{i=1}^n(b^{-1}x_i)ay_i$,  then it follows from the definition of $I$ that $1_A\in I$.

Comment: What perplexed me is the first statement.$GL(A)$ is open,then there exists invertible element in $I$.How to prove this conclusion?

Comment: Since $GL(A)$ is open, if $GL(A)\cap I$ is empty, then by definition $I$ is not dense.  But we know $I$ is dense, so $GL(A)\cap I$ cannot be empty.

Comment: Thanks,I always forget the equivalent definition of dense set.What I remember is the following:a  set S is dense in X  if $\bar{S}=X$.